# How to get imageUrl using Jquery in magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.0

I want to change Image src using jquery in magento2,

So how can I get Imageurl in jQuery?

```
    <field name="default_template">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Ktpl\BannerManagement\Model\Config\Source\Template</item>
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Demo template</item>
                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">default_template</item>
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Ktpl_BannerManagement/js/form/element/defaultTemplate</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
    <field name="default_image">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Ktpl_BannerManagement/form/element/defaultTemplate</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
```

defaultTemplate.html

```
    <img alt="demo"  class="article_image" id="mp-demo-image">
    <div class="admin__field field field-load_template " data-ui-id="ktpl-bannerslider-banner-edit-tab-banner-fieldset-element-form-field-load-template" style="">
                        <label class="label admin__field-label" for="banner_load_template" data-ui-id="ktpl-bannerslider-banner-edit-tab-banner-fieldset-element-note-banner-label"><span></span></label>
                <div class="admin__field-control control">
                    <div id="banner_load_template" class="control-value admin__field-value" style=""><button id="id_lq27ZKqKzkY3i4p7JLoi57aNy7f2PDSk" title="Load Template" type="button" class="action-default scalable" data-ui-id="widget-button-0">
                    <span>Load Template</span>
                   </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>
```

if I will update default_template value I want to change default_image src using jQuery

Comment: Do you need it in .phtml file or seperate JS file ?

Comment: In custom js file @AasimGoriya

Comment: Please check my ans.

Comment: but i want it in admin ui form

Comment: do you have .phtml file for your admin form page ?

Comment: check in question i have update the code

Comment: Please specify from where do you want to get image url ? please provide me more details so I can guide you better way

Comment: Please add custom phtml for your admin Form using XML file, then add provided code in your phtml.

Answer (score 6):

You can add JS following way in your .phtml file

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Vendor_Module/js/custom-js": {
            "imageURL": "<?= $imageUrl; ?>"
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Now in your custom JS file you can get your Image URL using following way.
So in **Vendor_Module/web/js/custom-js.js** file your JS code look like below.

```
define([
        "jquery"
    ], function($){
        "use strict";

        function customFunction(config, element) {
            var imgURL = config.imageURL; //config.imageURL is already defined in your .phtml file
        }; 
        return customFunction; 
    });
```